# How to tell Firefox to skip connections going to a specific address?

Tags: firefox

Quite a number of Web sites use the same connection to some Ajax site, which I assume is used to provide some JavaScript to various sites. Where I live, the connection to this is extremely slow, so any Web site using this is also slow to load. The status bar always reports attempting to connect to that. "File" --> "Save Page As..." then "Open File..." is sometimes the only way to view the pages which sometimes never finish loading. Is there any way I can tell Firefox to just ignore the connections requesting information from that server? Even if the page doesn't have all of the decorations, it is better than waiting endlessly.

Comment: If you use [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/), you could add a custom filter rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have root access and you are willing to apply a hack system-wide (so it will affect other users on the same machine too), a quick hack that will do what you want would be to list the offending site in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.3   www.problematic-site-name.example.com
```

(If you are *not* using Linux then replace `127.0.0.3` with `127.0.0.1` because `127.0.0.something-else` doesn't necessarily work with other operating systems)

This will trick the system to think that the offending name maps to a local IP address. Your web browser will hit up the local web server running on the same machine, which may or may not exist but one way or the other it will be fast instead of timing out.